Mean scores for survey responses in gtsummary
I am attempting to produce a table of weighted mean survey scores by categorical variables in gtsummary using the tbl_svysummary function.
How do I do this using survey weights, using the tbl_svysummary function? I've gone through the two examples that are close on here with solutions provided by Daniel Sjoberg, but I just don't really understand what is happening with them. I can do this by transposing the by and include arguments in tbl_svysummary, but then I have a whole new problem of the table being the wrong way round.
Here's some sample data:
dat <- structure(list(uuid = c("p41112019021430", "p41222013024584", 
"p41212017017560", "p41212017011700", "p41212019022003", "p41212019133026", 
"p41212017014434", "p41112019023063", "p41212019077561", "p41212017050030"
), age_cat = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
4L), levels = c("18-24", "25-44", "45-64", "65-74", "75+"), class = "factor"), 
    cvh_score = c(6, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1), weights = c(p41112019021430 = 0.360602284454939, 
    p41222013024584 = 5.00004172246093, p41212017017560 = 0.276025143197602, 
    p41212017011700 = 1.55086389757734, p41212019022003 = 2.20669366738008, 
    p41212019133026 = 0.878664071962474, p41212017014434 = 1.15252329666968, 
    p41112019023063 = 1.51638372307208, p41212019077561 = 2.1408232841115, 
    p41212017050030 = 0.282529671403006)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

dat_svy <- dat |> 
  srvyr::as_survey_design(
    ids = uuid, 
    weights = weights
  )

I can achieve what I am looking for without weights using the tbl_continuous function like follows:
tbl_01 <- gtsummary::tbl_continuous(
  dat, 
  variable = cvh_score, 
  include = c(age_cat), 
  statistic = list(
    everything() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  )
  ) 

tbl_01

which gives me the following:

How do I do this with weights?

I suggest using surveytable for this. The code is very simple:
library(surveytable)
dat_svy <- svydesign(ids = ~uuid, weights = ~weights, data = dat)
set_survey(dat_svy, opts = "general")
tab_subset("cvh_score", "age_cat")

Output:
cvh_score (for different levels of age_cat) {dat_svy}
┌───────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬──────┐
│ Level │ % known │ Mean │   SEM │   SD │
├───────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 18-24 │     100 │ 4.6  │ 0.626 │ 1.3  │
├───────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 25-44 │     100 │ 1.46 │ 0.818 │ 1.58 │
├───────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 45-64 │     100 │ 3.08 │ 0.627 │ 1.6  │
├───────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼──────┤
│ 65-74 │     100 │ 1    │ 0     │ 0    │
└───────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴──────┘

tab_subset() returns the table, so you can pipe it through to any other function that you want. You can also optionally send the table to CSV, HTML, or LaTeX.

Here's the solution I came up with:
weighted_mean <- dat_svy |>
  filter(!is.na(age_cat)) |>
  group_by(age_cat) |>
  summarize(mean = survey_mean(cvh_score), sd = survey_sd(cvh_score)) |>
  transmute(
    row_type = "level",
    label = age_cat,
    stat_3 = str_glue("{round(mean, 2)} ({round(sd, 2)})")
  ) |>
  add_row(
    row_type = "label",
    label = "Age",
    stat_3 = NA,
    .before = 1L
  )

table <- tbl_svysummary(
  dat_svy, 
  include = c("age_cat"), 
  label = list(
    age_cat ~ "Age" 
  ), 
  statistic = list(
    all_categorical() ~ "{n}"
  ),
  percent = "row", 
  missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>% 
      dplyr::left_join(
        weighted_mean, 
        by = c("row_type", "label")
      )
  ) |> 
  modify_column_unhide(columns = c("stat_3")) |> 
  modify_column_hide(columns = c("stat_0")) |> 
  modify_header(
    label = "**Characteristic**", 
    stat_3 = "**CVH Score**, Mean (SD)"
  )


You could do the calculations in the survey package, which gives you the SE, and then format the output using gt:
svyby(~cvh_score, ~age_cat, dat_svy, svymean) |>
  gt::gt() |>
  tab_footnote(footnote="cvh_score: Mean (SE)") |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_text(weight = "bold")),
    locations = cells_column_labels()
  ) |>
  fmt_number()


